# Why won't these polygons form from mesh.from_pydata?

Tags: python, mesh

I'm trying to make a fully connected sphere from pydata. The data is a 2D array that is converted to 3D spherical coordinates. I'm trying to zip up the two ends of the array with polygons. But for some reason they aren't forming. However, the FIRST one does form.

Here you can see the vertex indices forming the first polygon.

[image]

[image]

And here are the two first polygons

```
[(0, 864, 1727, 863),
 (864, 1728, 2591, 1727),
```

You can see the indices from the first polygon match those in the code.
Here you can see the other two indices of the second polygon which should also form.(It's 1728 if you can't see it)

[image]

Thus, by all logic that polygon should form too since it's the second element in the list of polygons. Is there some order I'm missing? Why does only the first polygon form?

EDIT:

Apparently the code works on a smaller sphere so.... it's some weird bug thing. It's curious.